# How can I solve the following equation for Yt?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am currently trying to solve the following equation for $Y_t$:

$$Y_t = A \ K_t^\alpha\ L_t^\beta \ [(s_t \ Y_t^{\gamma_y} \ P_{st}^{\gamma_p})^{\frac{1}{\sigma}} + (n_t \ Y_t^{\phi_y} \ P_{nt}^{\phi_p})^{\frac{1}{\sigma}}]^{\sigma}$$

Help would be highly appreciated. Cross posted in MathOverflow.

Comment: What makes you think it might be possible to do this?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Gerry. So this is a modified CD function for output in which energy demand functions $s_t Y_t^{\gamma_y} P_{st}^{\gamma_p}$ for renewable energies and the respective function for non renewable energies is inserted. Before taking FOC with respect to for example $s_t $ I need to rearrange the equation for $Y_t$.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Just because you need to do something, doesn't mean it can be done. Get rid of all the fluff, and you have $Y=a(bY^c+dY^e)^f$, and there's no reason to think you can solve this for $Y$ (except numerically).

Comment: I understand, Gerry. Thanks for the comment. Is it possible to solve the equation if c=d?

Comment: Do you mean, if $c=e$? Sure, then you get $Y=gY^h$, and that's easy to solve for $Y$.

Comment: So, are we OK now?

Comment: Earth to Raphael, come in, please.

Comment: Everything is fine! Apologies for the late response! Thank you very much Gerry! Great support! Highly appreciated.

Comment: Glad to hear everything is fine. Let me encourage you to write up an answer now, and post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

After suitable variable substitution and simplification, the equation can be rewritten in the form

$$z^\alpha=az+b.$$

This is not solvable analytically, except for a few rational values of $\alpha$.

On a plot, you see that this is the intersection of the power curve $z^\alpha$ with a straight line. There can be up to two solutions.

[image]

The number and location of the roots can be found by considering the parallel to the given line which is tangent to the curve at a $z$ such that $\alpha z^{\alpha-1}=a$.

Answer (score 0):

The following equation:
$$Y_t = A \ K_t^\alpha\ L_t^\beta \ [(s_t \ Y_t^{\gamma_y} \ P_{st}^{\gamma_p})^{\frac{1}{\sigma}} + (n_t \ Y_t^{\phi_y} \ P_{nt}^{\phi_p})^{\frac{1}{\sigma}}]^{\sigma}$$

can solely be solved for $Y_t$ if one assumes that $\gamma_y = \phi_y = \gamma$. Simplifying the equation to $Y_t = a [(b \ Y_t^{\gamma})^{\frac{1}{\sigma}} + (c \ Y_t^{\gamma})^{\frac{1}{\sigma}}]^{\sigma}$ we can see that $Y_t = a Y_t^{\gamma}(b^{\frac{1}{\sigma}} + c^{\frac{1}{\sigma}})^{\sigma} $ which solves for $Y_t = [a (b^{\frac{1}{\sigma}} + c^{\frac{1}{\sigma}})^{\sigma}]^{1-\gamma}              $.

Thanks to Gerry for the feedback & support!